# Instant update on loading of page as opposed to refresh

Tags: javascript, php

edit.php

```
<?php
if (((!empty($_GET["mode"])) && (!empty($_GET["ID"]))) && ($_GET["mode"] == "update")) {
    if (isset($_POST["updateSubmit"])) {
        if ((!empty($_GET["ID"])) && (!empty($_POST["FilmName"]))
            && (!empty($_POST["Producer"])) && (!empty($_POST["YearPublished"]))
            && (!empty($_POST["Stock"])) && (!empty($_POST["Price"]))) {
            $query = "UPDATE ProductConsole "
                . "SET FilmName = '" . $_POST["FilmName"] . "', "
                . "Producer = '" . $_POST["Producer"] . "', "
                . "YearPublished = '" . $_POST["YearPublished"] . "', "
                . "Stock = " . $_POST["Stock"] . ", "
                . "Price = '" . $_POST["Price"] . "' "
                . "WHERE ID=" . $_GET['ID'] . ";";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

            if ($result == false) {
                echo "<p>Updating failed.</p>";
            } else{
                echo "<p><br><br>Updated, please refresh page.</p>"; // CAN I AVOID REFRESHING PAGE?
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

So on the home page you can view products by table. You can click edit to edit that particular row. When I modify a value and navigate back to the home page, I have to manually refresh. Once I've edited the record, I have to refresh the page edit.php for it to retrieve the record. Here is the php for once the page is updated. I assume that's the only code you need. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Hmmm...if `Updated, please refresh` shows up when submitted, then the changes have been made and the page is already refreshed. Something else must be going on.

Comment: I have to wonder, what are you trying to "show' that is updated anyway? I see no html outputting updated values. Also, you have a mix of $_GET & $_POST....why is that?